# Keep getting 'map of undefined' when displaying table data, React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nivo-react

I'm trying to display years when the input is changed to 'years' using State, but I'm having an issue.

```
const handleChange = (e, countMonth,countYear) =>{

      
  if(e.target.value === 'months'){
    setMonths(countMonth)

  } else if( e.target.value === 'year'){
    setMonths(countYear)
  
  }


}
```

I'm trying to display different data when year is clicked with this map method:

```
      <tbody>
        {
          months.map(({ date, count }, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{date}</td>
            <td>{count}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
```

I keep getting the error `'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'`

Here is the full sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-clarke-szge3?file=/src/data.js

Comment: Here's how you're calling `handleChange` which requires 3 parameters ~ `onChange={(e) => {handleChange(e)}}`. See the problem?

Comment: Your `handleChange` handler expects 3 arguments but you pass only the first. `countMonth` and `countYear` aren't in scope as fas as I can tell.

Comment: Yeah i tried adding those two as arguments but still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

In your sandbox code, I tried putting console logs, found that `countYear` is `undefined` and that's is being set to `months`.

Ideally you should validate `countYear` before its being set to state `months` [`else if( e.target.value === 'year' && countYear)`] or fix the root cause why `countYear` is `undefined`

```
const handleChange = (e, countMonth,countYear) =>{
      
  if(e.target.value === 'months'){
    console.log('countMonth ', countMonth)
    setMonths(countMonth)

  } else if( e.target.value === 'year'){
    console.log('countYear ', countYear)
    setMonths(countYear)
  
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the purpose of answering to help "fix the root cause why `countYear` is `undefined`" versus just pointing out the code doesn't work? How is this a useful answer?

Comment: could you put that into the sanbox pleas?